# Run macro from desktop, hidden & with minimum system impact

Tags: windows, vba, excel

Recently the IT policy at my work changed, and all scripts I have been using (`.bat` `.cmd` `.py`) no longer work. Where possible I have converted these to VBA macros that run in workbooks - as these are still enabled.

Here are two macros to schedule a force shutdown/ cancel it (respectively)

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Application.Visible = False
Shell "SHUTDOWN /s /f" '/Scheduled shut down, /Forced (ignores any unsaved)
End Sub
```

And in a 2nd workbook

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Application.Visible = False
Shell "shutdown /a" '/Abort scheduled shutdown
Application.Quit
End Sub
```

As you can see the macros run on `Workbook_Open()` events, with `Application.Visible = False`. The intent is for a desktop shortcut to open these workbooks as invisibly and quickly as possible.

#### Issues & solutions

- It's slower - I used to run this as a batch script, now Excel has to open to run it

  - I've made it an `.xlsb` to reduce opening time, is there a faster method?
  - I'm *not* asking how to speed up my workbook, I just mean is there a different way of saving the file (an addin perhaps?) which can run without Excel opening?
  - I've also only chosen to close Excel when shutdown is aborted, not when it is scheduled, as if Excel is already open then the cancel macro opens faster (which is essential if I accidentally schedule shutdown)
- The running is not invisible; although the workbook itself is never shown, the Excel startup image appears

  - I have tried adding switches to the shortcut target (`/e` to prevent standard template loading `/r` for readonly in the hope that it wouldn't display the sheet) - but they don't work
  - `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE" /r /e "C:\Users\USERNAME\Documents\start.xlsb"`
- The `Application` calls are Excel-wide. Sometimes, I schedule a shutdown *before* I've saved everything. (I know it will take me a few seconds to save so I schedule shutdown first)

  - That was fine when I ran these as `.bat`/`.cmd` scripts, but if I run these and Excel is open then everything closes (or becomes invisible - although I have no way of checking which one), which is not ideal when I'm still working on something.
  - Can I make sure these only hide themeselves? Would opening another instance of Excel help?

#### TL;DR

- I've saved macros as `Workbook_Open()` events in `.xlsb` workbooks, which run from desktop shortcuts
- How can I improve on this in

  - Making the process hidden
  - Making the process faster
  - Preventing the process screwing up the rest of Excel
- By

  - Flags in the desktop shortcut
  - Changes to the macro code
  - Changing how the macro is saved
- And

  - **Without** just converting to scripts as they are blocked

NB, I would do this with VBS to circumvent Excel entirely, but that is blocked too

Comment: If you're issuing a command to shut-down, why is Excel briefly splashing up a real issue? Have you considered a .js? That said, perhaps you should speak to those who have implemented the IT policy change and get some dispensation to run a specific set of commands on a specific machine etc. rather than try to 'workaround' the increased security measures?

Comment: @CLR True it's not a huge issue, just aesthetic. The main issue is with it shutting down other excel instances in the process. I've spoken with IT and he says he could create exceptions if I gave him the names, but I can tell it would be a bit annoying for him, and I would like to find a workaround so that I can create new stuff without having to add it to the exception list. How would a .js work? I thought they only ran on websites, not through the desktop (I have little experience though, so I wouldn't know how to make one to carry out the function)

Comment: I've no idea about .js files myself, I've just heard security people mention that Windows will execute them. *Thinking aloud now* - if it's just shutdown you're after, would it be feasible to have a copy of that particular  exe file, renamed to something obscure, that would be permissible to the IT policy?

Answer (score 0):

Fastest is a desktop shortcut with the shutdown command, i.e. `%WINDIR%\system32\shutdown.exe /s /f`

Comment: * sy**s**tem32 I'm guessing (can't make a one character edit). Unfortunately that has the same admin issues (doesn't it try to bring up the command prompt?)

Comment: I've used this for many years on XP and Win7 and don't recall needing admin privilege. I am after all shutting down my own pc, which is the same operation as done via Start -> Shutdown

Comment: Sorry, poor wording, not admin privileges; it is blocked by the no-scripts policy I mentioned and will not execute.